# Auto-Fill Consecutive Numerals Within Text for Many Consecutive Rows

Tags: excel, vba, formula, numeric, counting

I need the numerals contained/mixed within row text to count consecutively as I duplicate the rows.

```vb
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C12").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C62").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C13").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C62").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C...").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C62").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C15000").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C62").Value
```

e.g.

```vb
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C4660").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C19").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C4661").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C19").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C4662").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C19").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C4663").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C19").Value
```

It is the "C466*" value that I would like to autofill with consecutive gains. I cannot find any help on other forums.

Further Explanation

- In the Rows (as seen below) the Value "("C4660"), ("C4661"), ("C4662"), ("C4663"), etc.), is contained in each Row.  This ("C*") references the cell which will have data from another sheet transferred into.
- I am just beginning to write the macros and I am looking for an efficient way to duplicate these rows but with the ("C*") value gaining by one in each consecutive row. I am trying to avoid having to touch every row.
- My very First ("C*") value is ("C12"). My final ("C*") value needs to be roughly ("C15000").
- The Value of ("C19") in each row does also have to change.  With Tim's suggestion, I have reduced the lines.  I added a more detailed example of what I have come up with.  When the ("C19") value gets to ("C250"), I have to circle back to the top.

The lines I have added should show more of how I have to structure it.

```vb
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C12:C21").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C19").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C22:C31").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C20").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C32:C41").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C21").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C42:C51").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C22").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C52:C61").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C23").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C62:C71").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C24").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C72:C81").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C25").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C82:C91").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C26").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C92:C101").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C27").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C102:C111").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C28").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C112:C121").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C29").Value
Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C122:C131").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C30").Value
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question with additional information? I am not really understanding what you need exactly.

Comment: You can do this in one line: `Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C12:C15000").Value = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C19").Value`  PS your use of Rows is a little confusing here - worksheets have "rows", whereas code has "lines"

Comment: @Tim - Thank you for clarifying the language for me.  I am just learning about this stuff.  I have followed a couple forums and have been trying to read as much as possible.  I was asked to try to learn some basics.  I have edited my question once again.  I have added more lines.  I tried to create a series of lines that would truncate what I am transferring with the Macro. I see what you did with your example line.  I think I have an idea for how to utilize fewer lines (thanks to you).  If you have a minute, please check out my edit and see if you agree with my changes (Suggestions Welcome)

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop for this:

```
Dim i As Long, rngDest As Range, rngSource As Range

Set rngDest = Sheets("ENTR Ext Budget").Range("C12:C21")
Set rngSrc = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C19")

For i=1 to 100 'for example

    rngDest.Value = rngSrc.Value

    Set rngDest = rngDest.Offset(10, 0) 'move destination down 10 rows
    Set rngSrc = rngSrc.Offset(1, 0)    'move source down 1 row

    'not sure if this is what you meant...
    If rngSrc.Row = 250 then 
        Set rngSrc = Sheets("BPC-SAP Grant Upload").Range("C19")
    End if
Next i
```

Comment: Tim - You are the man! Thank you very much.  Do you know of any good sources I can utilize to learn more about Excel VBA coding?

Comment: I like books when learning something new, but realize that's a bit old-school these days.  I started with the Excel 95 (!) version of this one - https://www.amazon.com/Excel-Power-Programming-Spreadsheets-Bookshelf/dp/1119067723